# Где хранить refresh token и что в нем должно находится?

Tags: авторизация, jwt

В интернете куча статей про JWT где используется два токена, но ни в одной я не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос.

#### Где хранить?

У меня есть несколько предположений о том где можно хранить `refresh token`:

1. Отдельная запись в базе
2. Хранить на клиенте
3. Хранить внутри `access` токена

Первый вариант не плох,не так сложен в реализации и как мне кажется довольно безопасен, но я не знаю насколько это правильный способ.

Второй вариант подразумевает, что при вводе логина и пароля формируется пара токенов (`refresh и access`) которые хранятся на клиенте.
Токены сохранятся в `cookie` или `local storage` и передаются в теле запроса. 
Возможно стоит шифровать `refresh` токен.

Третий вариант видел в статье на Хабре, но уже не могу ее найти.
Суть заключается в том что access токен содержит в себе зашифрованный `refresh` токен.

---

#### Что должен содержать?

Если `refresh` токен будет хранится в базе, то возможно будет достаточно хранить время его жизни и идентификатор который хранить внутри `access` токена для поиска по нему.

Если токен хранится на клиенте, то так же можно записать в него время жизни, подпись от `access` токена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логика где-то такая:

**AccessToken** - имеет **малое время жизни**, и является **многоразовым**, его добавляют к каждому последующему запросу

**RefreshToken** - имеет **большое время жизни**, и является **одноразовым**, его используют для обновление пары токенов

Для наглядности приведу несколько ситуаций:

1. Атакующий заполучил **AccessToken**, это дает ему возможность использовать сервис, на время жизни этого токена, после истечения которого ему понадобится передать **RefreshToken**
2. Атакующий заполучил **RefreshToken**, если он им воспользуется, то это разлогинит пользователя, и даст возможность атакующему использовать сервис  до следующего логина пользователя, так как при этом он сгенерирует новую пару токенов а старые будут невалидны
3. Атакующий заполучил **Логин и пароль**, атакующий может использовать сервис, до следующей смены пароля (при условии что для смены пароля требуется старый пароль)

Касательно того где хранить токены:

1. Если атакующий получает доступ к клиенту, то может перехватить
   расшифрованный токен/логин+пароль. Поэтому шифрование тут не решит проблеммы также как и отдельное хранение токена
2. Если атакующий получает доступ к каналу связи, то смотри пункт 1
3. Хранить один токен внутри другого, в чем профит? Можно тогда вообще использовать только один **AccessToken**